# ASP 3 - Retirar espaço no meio do texto

Tags: asp

Seguinte, esse texto é retirado de um pdf, e postado em um textare (fckeditor), porém ele vem todo desalinhado.

Assim, por exemplo:

```
pergunta

a)resposta 1
  b)resposta 1
c)resposta 1
     d)resposta 1
e)resposta 1
```

Gostaria de receber esse texto, desalinhado, e exibir ele dessa forma, sem os espaços que estão a esquerda.

```
pergunta

a)resposta 1
b)resposta 1
c)resposta 1
d)resposta 1
e)resposta 1
```

Obs: Tenho uma função em JQUERY+REGEX que faz isso, porém não funciona no fckeditor, só no textarea puro, então pensei talvez em uma função em ASP. Me atenderia perfeitamente, para o que preciso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78041/discussion-between-rod-and-dvd).

Comment: Agora creio que irá funcionar. Faz um teste: http://ticianawerner.com.br/teste1/teste.asp

Comment: @dvd já tá abrindo com erro. linha 92, left

Comment: funcionou. kkk usou regex e mais o que? Como fez pra achar o espaço?

Comment: @dvd se eu fizer algumas estripulias dará erro, sabe como é o usuario né. Tem como ao invez do erro exibir uma mensagem. Tipo: Formate corretamente a questão. Com o tratamento de Erro do asp dá pra fazer isso?